# Are both of these ways to calculate the limit of a complex function correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I am studying complex limits, and I noticed that Pennisi's Complex Analysis gives a  rather formal approach to calculating a limit, compared to what I usually do. I will illustrate it in the following example, taken from Pennisi.

> Show that:$$\lim_{z\to3i}\frac{(z^2+9)}{z-3i}=6i$$

I would approach this the usual way.
$$\lim_{z\to3i}\frac{(z^2+9)}{z-3i}=\lim_{z\to3i}\frac{(z+3i)(z-3i)}{z-3i}=\lim_{z\to3i}z+3i=6i$$

However, the book tells us this:

> For $z\neq 3i $ we have:
>   $$|f(z)-6i|=\left|\frac{(z+3i)(z-3i)}{z-3i}-6i\right|=|z-3i|$$
>   For any $\epsilon>0$, let us choose $\delta=\epsilon$. Then:
>   $|f(z)-6i|<\epsilon$, whenever $0<|z-3i|<\delta$ , from which the limit now follows.

To be honest, I don't quite understand how the last line proves the limit, and also don't know if there is any benefit in using this approach as opposed to the one I used before, since they seem to get to the same answer, but the second way is much more laborious.

Answer (score 1):

The approach showed in the book emphasises the use of the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-criterion. That is how you proof such a limit by definition!

So if you do not know anything about continuity you have to do it that way.

Your way of 'proving' just states the result, but how did you achieve it?

From the expression $\lim_{z\to 3i} z+3i=\dotso$ you could also attempt the same proof to be 'extra correct'.